# Can I make the Omega theme to either be or not to be responsive depending on the capability of the device to properly scale the site

Tags: theming

I have a site which needs to be responsive to several devices (mobiles and tablets)

I will do this using the [Omega](http://drupal.org/project/omega) theme. Then I have the option to make the theme **Responsive**. In this way the general layout of the site changes based in the size of the screen device.

So far so good.

I need to change this behavior in this way: if the device is capable of scaling and showing the site in an acceptable way (ex: like the iPhone(iOS) and Galaxy S2(Android) do) then the theme should no behave like responsive and show the site in its **normal** layout.

My question: Can I make the Omega theme to either be or not to be responsive depending on the capability of the device to properly scale the site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really get your question.

Omega handles responsive changes by media queries.  The default is to load a new stylesheet (narrow, normal, or wide) based on the rules you setup.  If a browser doesn't support media queries, then just global and default get loaded.  If you want to enable responsive layouts for older browsers, then you can enable the JS support.

Also, nothing prevents you from using media queries in the global and default stylesheets.  This is how I handle retina and retina-like display graphics.

Comment: not sure if I understand you but the `Samsung Galaxy S2` phone is capable of scaling and showing the site in a good way, and if I check the theme to be responsive then this phone shows the `narrow` css file. I need that this phone (and other similar to this one) load the `normal` css file instead

Comment: So you want to use media queries for some users and device detection for other users?  Device detection is a losing battle.  Too many devices, and the landscape changes way too quickly.

Comment: that's the idea, yes. Then, you say that the theme will be either responsive or not responsive at all?

Comment: I agree with MPD. What you are trying to do is essentially going against the entire point of responsive design.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can trigger [contexts](http://drupal.org/project/context) on specific devices using [mobile tools](http://drupal.org/project/mobile_tools), and you can probably turn Omega's responsiveness off with [Delta](http://drupal.org/project/delta).

I've never pulled such configuration, so please try out and give some feedback ;)

Comment: thanks I'll try it. I've never used this configuration either. But my client want it like this.

Comment: I just saw that there is no stable version of mobile tools for D7. The author put a clear warning about using it in production sites...

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the 'ressponsiveness' of the Omega theme in it's settings, once you have created your subtheme. Just disable the responsive grid. You'll find the setting to do this at:

```
[your-domain]/admin/appearance/settings/[your-theme-name].
```

[image]